# How to update SCIChart's live data when scrolling in scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, scichart

I have successfully implemented `SCICharts` live data, Like `ECGLiveMonitoring` example on Official `SCICharts`. I have added 9 charts in `UIScrollView`. Everything is working fine. The problem is when i scroll my ScrollView it stop drawing on `SCICharts` and after scroll stops it start drawing again.

All the data is coming from to a connected Socket and after a **35.12** milliseconds a function is called that updates the chart data.

I found that to update UI while scrolling we need to add Timer to RunLoop 
So i added Following Line to my Time function.

After adding the line i have added "print" Statement to code for show data is coming from socket.

I works fine with print statement but doesn't update my Charts until the scroll stops.

````
       if _timer == nil {
           _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInteval, target: self, selector: #selector(drawData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
//The line i added in my code
           RunLoop.current.add(_timer, forMode: .tracking)
       } else {
           _timer.invalidate()
           _timer = nil
       }
   }```
````